# Field extension coming from quotient maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are rings such that $R\subset S$ with unique maximal ideals $m_R$ and $m_S$, respectively. Suppose $m_R=m_S\cap R$. Is it true then that $S/m_S$ is a field extension of $R/m_R$?

This is just a generalization of a specific example of something in the exposition of a text I'm reading. It doesn't seem that we can just use the lattice isomorphism theorem since the quotients are different.

Comment: Yes; it is true. The canonical (injective) image of $S/ \mathfrak m_S$ is a subfield of $R/\mathfrak m_R$.

Comment: So the map just reduces elements of $R/m_R$ mod $m_S$?

Comment: Yes, it's just as simple. B.t.w. , I see that in my comment above, I had swapped $R$ and $S$